# Mutiple dependency declarations to missing classes in 'SQLiteDatabase' class

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I imported the `'SQLiteDatabase'` class present in '`android.database.sqlite`' package, into my project.I went into the class declaration to find the `opendatabase` function, but i noticed that the class was full of errors and was importing certain undefined/undeclared classes, like:

```
import android.annotation.IntDef;
import android.annotation.IntRange;
import android.annotation.NonNull;
import android.annotation.Nullable;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDebug.DbStats;
import android.os.SystemProperties;
```

These classes are used throughout the '`SQLiteDatabase`' class.

I tried to invalidate caches and restart the AS IDE, but the error still persisted.

I went into the sdk manager and downloaded all the required core android packages, but still nothing changed.

Finally, I checked out the documentation to see if something was wrong with my sdk. The documentation too did'nt recognize these import calls. like, `android.annotation` package does'nt even declare a `IntDef` or `IntRange`class, which has been imported in `SQLiteDatabase`. It gives the same, could resolve symbol error.

Answer (score 0):

After doing research for a while, I found an answer to my own question. I'm answering just in case it might help others stuck in this error/problem. The classes that were imported are hidden classes, tagged with annotation @hide.
Refer to [this article](https://code.google.com/archive/p/doclava/wikis/JavadocTags.wiki#@hide) for more.

Hidden classes (even if they are public in the Java sense) are removed from android.jar file containing specific platform API dependencies, like API level 27. Hence you get the error when you try to import something like Nonnull, service manager, etc . Hidden classes are those that Google does not want to be part of the documented public API.